# Ternary Operator - Is there a possible bug in React's conditional rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx, conditional-operator

Currently, I am developing with Node.js and React and got a strange problem where I am not sure if I am missing something or if it is a bug on React's side.

What I want to do is to use the ternary operator to render conditional HTML like this:

```js
...
{
  missingTradingSystemNameError
  ?
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  :
    duplicateTradingSystemNameError
    ?
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    :
      null
}
...
```

Both ternary operator conditions are stateful variables in my JSX.Element function. However, doing it like that leads to multiple errors in the following form:

**Error:**

```
React Hook "React.useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render
```

Funny enough, if I add a third (useless) nested condition in place of *null*, then everything is working as intended:

```js
...
{
  missingTradingSystemNameError
  ?
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  :
    duplicateTradingSystemNameError
    ?
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    :
      <<condition3>>
      ?
        null
      :
        null
}
...
```

*condition3* is a third stateful variable, but as you can see the additional condition does nothing and it should therefore be possible to omit it. Is this a React bug or am I missing something crucial here?

(P.S.: Please forgive me the code's unusual indentation but for me this is currently the most readable solution to more complex JSX code blocks)

**Edit 1:**

To provide some further requested details, here is my simplified useEffect() code block:

```js
const [missingTradingSystemNameError, setMissingTradingSystemNameError] = React.useState(false);
const [duplicateTradingSystemNameError, setDuplicateTradingSystemNameError] = React.useState(false);

...

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.tradingSystemDialog && resetTradingSystemDialogOnNextOpen) {
      ...
      
      setMissingTradingSystemNameError(false);
      setDuplicateTradingSystemNameError(false);
      
      ...
    }
  }, [
    props.tradingSystemDialog,
    resetTradingSystemDialogOnNextOpen,
    tickFields,
    consolidatedFields
  ]);
```

**missingTradingSystemNameError** is set via **setMissingTradingSystemNameError** and **duplicateTradingSystemNameError** is set via **setDuplicateTradingSystemNameError**. As you can see, these stateful variables are potentially altered in useState() but they are not in the dependencies of useState().

Comment: Where's the bit that calls `useEffect()`?

Comment: Please a [mcve]

Comment: I just added additional information about my useEffect() function to the post. I'm going to have a look if I am able to create a minimal reproduceable example but this might be difficult as the code is directly connected to much more complex functionality. I could imagine that the issue does not exist in a simpler environment but I will have a look at what I can do.

Comment: Whenever you're dealing with a large library like React, assume the problem is yours, not the library's. In this case, using nested conditional operators is a code smell that you've not abstracted enough.

Comment: Yeah, I could imagine that the issue is on my side but I just do not see any approach how to tackle this problem right now. On a top level, when using stateful variables like `const [variable, setVariable] = React.useState(...);`, there should not be much to it to use them as conditions for conditional rendering. I don't see the connection to the mentioned error output right now (which is, in the described case, caused by other stateful variables than the ones which are used in the conditions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing a minimal reproducible example would be the best, but the context is too complex in my case. However, what I did is to remove more and more code to examine if one small part is causing the issue. Now I came to the conclusion that the following code snippet at some other location in the file is problematic and causes the mentioned code to fail or at least behave in a strange way:

```js
...
{
  basicShortSettingsError
  ?
    <div className={classes.error}>
      <ErrorOutline
        className={classes.errorIcon}
      />
      <Typography className={classes.sectionError} variant="body2">
        {
          parseFloat(positionSizeShort) > parseFloat(maxContractsShort)
          ?
            "Position size > maximum contracts"
          :
            "Set position size and maximum contracts"
        }
      </Typography>
    </div>
  :
    null
}
...
```

For some reason, the conditional part inside the **Typography** tag worked before but is now causing errors if I extend the code at some other point in the file by the content which I mentioned in the question.

To clarify, this is the code snippet causing problems:

```js
<Typography className={classes.sectionError} variant="body2">
  {
    parseFloat(positionSizeShort) > parseFloat(maxContractsShort)
    ?
      "Position size > maximum contracts"
    :
      "Set position size and maximum contracts"
  }
</Typography>
```

**positionSizeShort** and **maxContractsShort** are also stateful variables and I am not sure why the code was working just fine before and is now failing, but at least I have found the problem's root now where I can probably do a workaround.

If anyone has a better idea why exactly this code is problematic, it is more than welcomed to share your thoughts here as I have no real answer for my issue.